# $_GET or $_SESSION for passing variable

Tags: php, html

Hello monsters of programming. I just want to ask a question about using `$_SESSION` and `$_GET`. When to use `$_GET` and `$_SESSION`? what is the best for passing variable? Im just new to php and html and i don't know what is the best practice. Can someone help me to understand both of them?

Here is the example of my code. I used `$_SESSION` for passing the variable `$newsid;`

here is the edit.php

```
  <?php
          session_start();
           include_once('connection.php');
           $sql ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id";
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                   $newsid = $row['news_id'];
                    $title = $row['news_title'];
                     $date = $row['news_date'];
                     $content = $row['news_content'];
                     $newsimage = $row['news_image'];

                     ?>
                     <div class="fix single_news">
                       <div class="single_image">
                           <img src="<?php echo $newsimage; ?>" style="width:200px; height:140px; alt="court">
                       </div>
                       <a href="#"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                       <p><?php echo $date; ?></p>
                     <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                     </div>
                     <form  action="" method="post">
                       <input type='hidden' name="news_id" value="<?php echo $newsid;?>">
                     <input type="submit" name="esubmit" value="edit" />
                     </form>
                      <hr>
                    <?php
                     }
                   if(isset($_POST['esubmit'])){
                     $_SESSION['news_id'] = $_POST['news_id'];
                      header('Location: edit2.php');
                      }
                     ?>
```

here is the edit2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['news_id'];
include_once('connection.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                         $title = $row['news_title'];
                         $date = $row['news_date'];
                         $content = $row['news_content'];
                         $newsimage = $row['news_image'];
                         }

                         ?>   
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


    <form method="post" action ="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Title<input type ="text" name ="title" value="<?php echo $title;?>"/><br>
        Date<input type ="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>" /><br>
        Content<textarea name="content"><?php echo $content;?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
        <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
        <img id="blah" src="<?php echo $newsimage;?>" alt="your image" style="width:200px; height:140px;"/>

    </form>
    <hr>


<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `SESSION` is almost ***always*** better than GET, I'm trying to think of a situation where GET would be better, but as long as everything is on the same website on the same hosting environment (server) then no, SESSION is the way to do it, every time.

Comment: then using $_SESSION to pass my variable $news_id is okay?

Comment: Can you look at my code sir? if it's okay.

Comment: it's much better than `$_GET` .

Comment: get - is better for bookmarking, if you put a search variable for instance in a session and some one bookmarks that page, when they come back its lost. we had some major issues with this. get is better if your want a search engine to index something, its not going to keep sessions.

Comment: @Dagon cheers for that, I had never considered bookmarking, although I hazard that URL specifics is more the realm of `mod_rewrite` than GET data, but yes.... good point

Comment: hello sir @Dagon Is my code is okay? i used $_SESSION to pass variable $newsid.

Comment: I agree with @Martin - You should keep your code as it is (using sessions). **However...** you are wide open for [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Since you're using `mysqli_*` you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @nethken you may be looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Code Review Stack Exchange where people will review your code, this seems to be what you're after....

Comment: As long as you are aware that the session goes away after about 30 minutes then you will be fine. There are various places to record stuff. 1) database (not session) - you control totally. 2) session - which is really a cookie looked after by PHP. 3) A cookie looked after by you. They are cookies so the client can destroy them. Which means no session. How you get that information back is up to you. $_GET is fine for URL parameters.

Comment: i dont know what "ok" is in this circumstance, we have given you enough advise to decide that for yourself.

Comment: @RyanVincent - Sessions goes away after the configured session timeout if you're inactive. If you refresh/click on another page on the same site, the timeout resets.

Comment: I've given an alternative solution here, [http://stackoverflow.com/a/38090996/5517143](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38090996/5517143). It uses `$_GET` superglobal to catch the news id and prepared statement to prevent any kind of SQL injection. Pick whichever method suits you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, i.e. people go for lunch, meetings etc. the chances are that the session will time out rather more often than we would like? 30 minutes is the default for PHP just a comment as to why I assume sessions last about 30 minutes is all.

Comment: @RyanVincent - Absolutely. I just added to your response since you just said that "session goes away after about 30 minutes". It's an important distinction that it only goes away if the user is inactive (no http request to the server) during that time.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,  Sorry, I completely misunderstood the point your were making. I assume we agree that the session is not the place to store information that needs to be accessed reliably after a few hours?

Comment: @RyanVincent - Yes. We are in 100% agreement! :)

Comment: Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is for parameters that are needed during that specific request (or can be easily carried over to other pages), e.g.:

- item IDs
- current page (pagination)
- user's profile name
- ...

[`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) is for data that needs to be persisted across multiple requests, e.g.:

- current user's ID
- shopping carts
- list filters
- ...

You should use the one that better suits your use case.

That being said, I'd consider storing `news_id` in the session a bad thing. What if I want to edit multiple items and open multiple browser tabs? I'll end up overwriting my data. Just because you *can* use sessions doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Then i just use $_GET for that sir?

Comment: Definitely. You don't even have to do anything special to carry the value over. A `<form>` with empty/undefined `action` attribute will use the current page's URL, including the GET parameters.