# Php Location Header - Variable

Tags: php, variables, header, location

I need some help with header location using variable.
I loose my variable.

How do I keep my $var?

```
    $var = $_GET['valueToSearch']
    (I get the correct value here)

if(isset($_POST['shipping']))
header("Location: shipping.php?valueToSearch=".$var);
exit;
}
```

This takes me to shipping, but I loose the $var value.

```
if(isset($_POST['shipping']))
$var = 'C2234';
header("Location: shipping.php?valueToSearch=".$var);
exit;
}
```

This works correctly.

How do I keep $var or any other suggestions?

I also tried:

```
window.location = "shipping.php?valueToSearch=" + $var;
```

Thanks

```
- More detail:

<?php
$var = $_GET['valueToSearch']; 
$query = "SELECT increment_id, status, created_at, method, shipping_description, company, name, telephone, email, suburb, state, country, data_transf_ordervalue_incl, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b %y')AS date FROM tblorder WHERE increment_id = '$var' order by created_at DESC";
    require_once('/../../private/dbcon_order.php');
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die ('Error');
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if(isset($_POST['shipping']))
{
header("Location: shipping.php?valueToSearch=".$var);
exit;
```

Comment: This is not reproducible with the few lines of code you have shown.

Comment: First of all this is not good practice for passing variables in this way.
Try to find out best practices here [en] https://phptherightway.com/  [ru] http://phptherightway.ru/

Secondly, what is the `$var` value in your example? Is it really `string`? CBroe is right - you should provide a few more lines of code or at least data.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe. I am new to php and want to learn.  Yes, $var is a string.  I will paste more code.  I get the $var from the previous page - that is why I use $_GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I'm answering based on "when user make a $_POST['shippping'], how do I get the $_POST['shipping'] value *after page redirection*"

```
$shipping = "";
// Assuming that "shipping" is a string type. 
if (isset($_POST["shipping"])) {
    $shipping = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "shipping", FILTER_DEFAULT);
} elseif ($_GET["shipping"])) {
    $shipping = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "shipping", FILTER_DEFAULT);
}


// Debug
echo "Your shipping value is : $shipping";

header("Location: shipping.php?valueToSearch=$var&shipping=$shipping");
```

So, your retained value is accessible with $_GET['shipping'] after the $_POST["shipping"] redirection.

Another way to store variable despite page redirection is by using $_SESSION. To do this, you can do such.

```
// To set a session value
$_POST["shipping"] = $_SESSION["shipping"];
// To get a session value
$shipping = $_SESSION["shipping"];
// To remove a session value
unset($_SESSION["shipping"]);
```

Another way to store variable despite page redirection is using user browser cookies, but the cookie is typically reserved for authentication purposes only, you can look it up here if you're interested. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: Thank you @Deviance.  I have a summary page, where I redirect to this page via link                   <td><a href="ordersummary.php?valueToSearch=<?php echo $row['increment_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['increment_id'];?> </td>.  On my detail page, I display the details of the one order.  From here I want to add new shipping details for the record.  If type is submit Shipping, then want to redirect to another page, keeping $var.  I do not know how to keep $var value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.

> I found this article:
> [$_GET or $_SESSION for passing variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110704/get-or-session-for-passing-variable)

I used a hidden field (increment) and then used $_SESSION to pass it between pages:

Set value:

```
$_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['increment'];
```

and on 2nd page: Get the value:

```
$valueToSearch = $_SESSION['var'];
```